# Creating a table for authorization in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First off, let me make it clear that I'm absolutely new to ASP.NET MVC, so my questions may seem a little confusing or out of order.

I'm trying to build an MVC web application using Code First workflow, and I have a problem with how I want to create my AccessControl table. I want to determine which role (my project has 3 roles) will have the authorization to access specific pages or menus (resources, in general). But I don't have the slightest idea what the columns of this table should be. I've seen columns like "Modified", "ModifiedBy", "Created", "CreatedBy", etc. in examples, but honestly I don't know what they actually mean.

I don't know if my question is too basic to be answered in this community, but I hope you could help me with this. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Take a look at; https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is too broad.

You can have an AccessControl table where you define roles and map such roles to users. So some users capture data and some authorize,

This can be done in your views and controllers using the [Authorize] attributes to check if the user is permitted to capture or Authorize a record.
Now you need to save this to the respective tables, that is where you will have the createdby xxxx , authorizedby xxxx, modifiedby xxxx columns to keep track of who did what. One of the heplful links is
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1